# Ajax call isn't returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty much a complete beginner at javascript and jQuery, so please bear with me.

I have a Spark-API running, and a web front-end that uses it through ajax calls.

I'm trying to call this function

```js
function getSpotifyURL(ms, name) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8081/playlist?ms=" + ms + "&name=" + name,
            dataType: "json",
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
```

The method is placed outside of:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
```

The reason it's outside is that I get an error upon calling it saying it's "undefined" if it's within $(document).ready.

The Spark-method is supposed to return a String (**and it does** when you try it directly through the browser).

The way I'm calling the getSpotifyURL-method is through a html button's "onclick". Like this:

```html
<a href='#' onclick='getSpotifyURL(" + data[i].duration + ",\"" + data[i].destination + "\")'>Create Spotify playlist for this trip</a>"
```

**The problem:**
The .done-block does nothing in my code. Nothing is printed to console.

**What I've tried:**

- Using "success" within the ajax part instead of .done
- Placing the function with $(document).ready(function() { ... }

I understand that you might need more information to be able to help me, but I'm not sure what else information to provide right now. So if there's something you need to know, just ask.

Ideas?

**SOLVED!**

I'm a dumb person and forgot to remove dataType: "json", as the Spark-server in this instance returned a String, not a json object. Anyway, thanks for your input everybody. Much appreciated.

Comment: I believe `.done()` is deprecated. Can you find the opened request in the *Network*  tab of your Developer's Tools ?

Comment: change `console.log(data);` `to console.log(data+"123");` so you can actually see if its reaching that part.

Comment: @Fluinc wouldn't be printed `undefined` or `null` that `console.log` was reached anyway ?

Comment: In getSpotifyURL, log ms and name before calling $.ajax, because I don't think you're passing the arguments you think you're passing to getSpotifyURL.

Comment: Just use alert under you function if alert call . Then copy paste ajax syntax from any site and try again .
Just Check your URL also and use inspect element > network for debug.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yea don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: add an error block and log the error to the console, also if you open the network tab in the developer console in chrome you can see if you are getting a network error

Comment: I had same problem when I didn't close Server Output Stream. Problem happened with Tomcat web server.

Comment: Please stop using `onclick` attribute. Since you use jquery consider using  its [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you bind your function onclick. There is a syntax error, as you can see on the browser console

```js
function getSpotifyURL(ms, name) {
    console.log("http://localhost:8081/playlist?ms=" + ms + "&name=" + name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' onclick='getSpotifyURL(" + data[i].duration + ",\"" + data[i].destination + "\")'>Create Spotify playlist for this trip</a>"
```

I  guess `data` is a variable, so you should call it without brackets

```
<a href='#' onclick='getSpotifyURL(data[i].duration, data[i].destination)'>Create Spotify playlist for this trip</a>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this <a> in generated through javascript, which is why I thought I had to use quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `undefined method` when you are placing the function inside the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` call is because you are using the `onclick` attribute to call the function. `$(document).ready(...)` is *not* in global context as to where you `onclick` attribute is, and would therefore not recognize it from within the document.ready resulting in your `undefined method` error.

When sending your Ajax request, you also need to specify a type of request (`GET` or `POST`) that you are making. I would also suggest restructuring your ajax call to look more like **@Moe's** answer.

If you want to get it inside the DOM, consider doing the following:

**HTML**

```
<!-- I gave the link a class name and removed the onclick= attribute -->
<a href="#" class="create-spotify-playlist">Create Spotify playlist for this trip</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // I gave the <a> link a click handler
    $(".create-spotify-playist").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevents link from requesting

        var ms = ??   //I'm not sure where you're getting your parameters from,
        var name = ?? //so you will probably have to figure out how to get those in here yourself

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8081/playlist",
            data: { ms: ms, name: name },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Success: " + data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("Error: " + data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I gave the link a click handler and placed it inside the `$(document).ready`, and by removing the `onclick` attribute from earlier, it can now be triggered from inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Although the problem is solved now (view my edit in #0), I considered your solution. The reason I chose onclick was that I needed the parameters since there would be a lot of js-generated <a> links with different values (ms and name). I tried your method at one point, but couldn't get it working properly.